# Como capturar o ID de usuario logado? PHP

Tags: php

O meu código de login onde depois do `(row > 0 )` tento selecionar o `id` do usuário que acabou de logar, jogo o resultado em uma variável e tento atribuída a uma session

```
$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['usuario']);
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['senha']);

$query = "select usuario from usuarios where usuario = '$usuario' and senha = md5('$senha')";

$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($row > 0){

    $busca  = "select IDUSUARIO from usuarios where usuario = '$usuario' ";
    $identificacao = mysqli_query($busca);
    $retorno = mysqli_fetch_array($identificacao);

    $_SESSION['iduser'] = $retorno;
    
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    header('Location: navegacao.php');
    exit();
}else{
    $_SESSION['nao_autenticado'] = true;
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```

Aqui tento atribuir essa session a uma variável e através de um insert tento inserir essa variável(id do usuário) como uma chave estrangeira, mas não esta funcionando.

```
$fk = $_SESSION['iduser'];

$query = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO imagens (imagem, tema, IDUSUARIO) VALUES ('$novonome', '$tema', '$fk')");
```

Comment: Você está usando [`session_start()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-start.php) antes de negociar com variáveis de sessão? Pergunto porque no exemplo dá para ver que não usa[`session_write_close()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-write-close.php) para salvar os dados e fechar a sessão atual antes de sair da página.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que selecionar o nome da coluna que está armazenado o ID do usuário.

```
$_SESSION['iduser'] = $retorno;
```

Assim você está recebendo um array da tabela com todas as colunas do usuário, você precisa selecionar a coluna do ID DO USUARIO

Tenta fazer assim...

```
$_SESSION['iduser'] = $retorno[ 'nomeDaColunaDoId' ];
```

Você não está conseguindo fazer o INSERT do ID DO USUÁRIO, porque você não está recebendo ele, tenta trocar a sua linha, e adiciona a que eu fiz. Provavelmente já resolverá seu problema.

Comment: Muito obrigado, consegui resolver o problema